# Trying to understand a part of the RSA algorithm...

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

The original paper published mentions this...

```
D(E(M)) ≡ (E(M))^d ≡ (M^e)^d (mod n) = M^(ed) (mod n)

E(D(M)) ≡ (D(M))^e ≡ (M^d)^e (mod n) = M^(ed) (mod n)

and

M^(ed) ≡ M^(k·φ(n)+1) (mod n) (for some integer k).
```

It's not clear to me how they arrived at the exponent for M in the last line...

k·φ(n)+1

Would anyone be able to help identify what I'm failing to grasp?

Comment: You see how it would be useful, given Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem?  And you want to know how we would arrange it so?

Comment: I know that the theorem is that a^(φ(n)) is equivalent to 1 mod n.  I'm just not sure why the exponent ends up as any integer k * φ(n) + 1.  I'm probably missing something simple but for some reason I can't figure it out

Comment: The point is that since we know how to factor $n$ (secretly), we are privy to $\varphi(n)$ as well, and then we can choose exponents $e,d$ so that $e\cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$.  That is, we know how to arrive at a nontrivial pair of multiplicative inverses modulo $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Ok thanks!  That helps with understanding it.  I had a mental block apparently as I wasn't grasping the fact that the exponent was just another way of viewing the modular math shown in the equation you just showed.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d$ is $e$'s inverse modulo $\varphi(n)$. so $d*e = 1(mod(\varphi(n))$. 
so $d*e = k*\varphi(n) + 1$ for some integer $k$..

Comment: I think I might have been overthinking it but I see now that the exponent was just another way of writing the equivalence of the modular math and it's remainder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

During key generation $e$ and $d$ were explicitly chosen such that $ed\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)}$, which means exactly that $ed=k\varphi(n)+1$ for some $k$.

Comment: Thank you for the help too